# Create Fisheye effect with JES with python, code results in blank image

Tags: python, jython, jes

This code runs without error and returns a blank image, printing both the color and the coord's show numbers that make sense but for some reason it seems nothing is being written.
Hopefully someone will see something I don't:

```
import math
def fisheye():
  file = pickAFile()
  pic = makePicture(file)  
  h = getHeight(pic)
  w = getWidth(pic)
  maxradius = sqrt(w**2 + h**2)/2
  fisheye = makeEmptyPicture(int(w+maxradius), int(h+maxradius),white)
  for x in range(0,w):
    for y in range(0,h):
      nyS = ( (2*x)/h ) - 1
      nxS = ( (2*y)/w ) - 1
      r = sqrt( nxS**2 + nyS**2 )
      if( r >= 0.0 and r <= 1.0 ):
        nr = (r + (1.0-r)) / 2.0
        if( nr <= 1.0 ):
          t = math.atan2(nyS,nxS)
          nx = nr*cos(t)
          ny = nr*sin(t)
          x2 = (((nx+1)*w)/2.0)
          y2 = (((ny+1)*h)/2.0)
          color = getColor(getPixel(pic, x, y))
          print max(color)
          setColor( getPixel(pic, int(x2),int(y2)) , color)
  explore(fisheye)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be your call to `setColor()`. In this statement you also have a call to `getPixel()` which is referencing `pic` and not `fisheye`.

Please alter this statement to the following:

`setColor( getPixel(fisheye, int(x2),int(y2)) , colour)`